# Lenovo A6000 Plus boots into recovery mode after downloading system updates

Tags: recovery-mode, stock-android, lenovo-a6000-plus

Today I downloaded updates for my Lenovo A6000 Plus. It asked for rebooting so I hit OK. But when it reboots, it says like:

> Android System Recovery <3e>.

The options it shows are:

- reboot system now
- apply update from ADB
- wipe data/factory reset
- wipe cache partition
- apply update from SD card

I have tried all the four options but with no good results. I attempted update from SD card, but I don't know what file it requires.

Comment: That sounds like a broken update. Normally you shouldn't need to select anything but "OK" – and the recovery ("<3e>") should pick the updates automatically. I'd try to contact the manufacturer (or carrier in case of a branded device – whoever sent the updates) in parallel to waiting for answers here. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I got the solution. Follow the instructions listed below, step by step:

1. At first, you have to download system software  in your memory card through another phone. Download the file from [here](http://www.favnetsoft.com/2015/09/download-official-stock-rom-lenovo-a6000-lollipop.html?m=1) (size of about 1GB; a ZIP file).

   **Note**: Aforesaid link is for Lenovo 6000 Plus.
2. Remove your phone's battery and insert the memory card in it.
3. Start your mobile. It would show the same screen as it did earlier. Tap "install updates from SD card" and navigate to the file you have downloaded.
4. Select the ZIP file you have downloaded.

Now enjoy the latest Lollipop version on your mobile and your problem is also solved.